collect2.exe: error: ld returned 116 exit status
windows 10, gcc is installed via msys2, path: "C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin".
When compiling with g++, i get an error "collect2.exe : error: ld returned 116 exit status.",
example: g++./project.cpp - o./projcet.exe.
If i type g+ --version in the command line, it outputs:
"g++.exe (Rev 3, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.1.0    Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.......", i think that that is, there are no problems with path.
if i compile in the msys2 shell, that program is built without problems. Also via Qt, if i choose     gcc from msys2, the program is built without problems.
If i collect via cmake, I also get an error "collect2.exe : error: ld returned 116 exit status."
What could be the problem when I try to compile in cmd or powershell?
I checked the paths to g++.
Reinstalled msys2.
Updated via pacman -Syu, -Su
g++ -v -o outputfile.exe example1.cpp:

g++ : Using built-in specs.
g++ -v .\example1.cpp -o example1.exe > compile_log2.txt 2>&1
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Using built-in specs.:String) [], RemoteException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-14.1.0/configure --prefix=/ucrt64 --with-local-prefix=/ucrt64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 
> --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/ucrt64/include --libexecdir=/ucr
t64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c+
> +,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,rust,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-
graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch
>  --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-n
ls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/ucrt64 --with-mpfr=/ucrt64 --with-
mpc=/ucrt64 --with-isl=/ucrt64 --with-pkgversion='Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/
MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --with-boot-ldflags=-static
> -libstdc++ --with-stage1-ldflags=-static-libstdc++
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 14.1.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'example1.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=nocona'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/g
cc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/ -D_REENTRANT .\example1.cpp -quiet -dumpbase example1.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=gener
ic -march=nocona -version -o C:\Users\b1sha\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3MKs8x.s
GNU C++17 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) version 14.1.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
compiled by GNU C version 14.1.0, GMP version 6.3.0, MPFR version 4.2.1, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.26-GMP

warning: GMP header version 6.3.0 differs from library version 6.2.1.
warning: MPFR header version 4.2.1 differs from library version 4.2.0-p9.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw3
2/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/
14.1.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/
14.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/
14.1.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "D:/a/msys64/ucrt64/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/ucrt64/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64
> -mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "D:/a/msys64/ucrt64/include"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/14.1.0
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/14.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/14.1.0/backward
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/include
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
Compiler executable checksum: d7a8e66cf2f26a72e527b0aced6104da
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'example1.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=nocona'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o C:\Users\b1s
ha\AppData\Local\Temp\cce3K6kt.o C:\Users\b1sha\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3MKs8x.s
COMPILER_PATH=C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/msys64/ucr
t64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/msys64/ucrt
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/
x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64
> -w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'example1.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=nocona' '-dumpdir' 'example1.'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-
w64-mingw32/14.1.0/liblto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/lto-wrapper.
exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\b1sha\AppData\Local\Temp\cctZ9Mtq.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin
> -opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-throug
h=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi3
2 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-o
pt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=
> -lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o example1.exe 
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64
> -w64-mingw32/14.1.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0 -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../li
b/gcc -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/msys64
> /ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
4.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../.. C:\Users\
b1sha\AppData\Local\Temp\cce3K6kt.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -lpthread -ladvapi32
>  -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x8
6_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/default-manifest.o C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/cr
tend.o
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 116 exit status


For starters, what are the contents of compile_log2.txt?

I have now made "g++ -v.\example1.cpp - o example1.exe > compile_log.txt 2>&1" through the msys2 shell and in powershell.
The main differences in the output are:     warning: GMP header version 6.3.0 differences from library version 6.2.1.
warning: MPFR header version 4.2.1 differences from library version 4.2.0-p9

I can't understand,     'pacman -Qi gmp' shows
'Name: gimp Version : 6.3.0-1..Groups: libraries';
'pacman -Qi mpfr' shows
'Name: mpfr Version : 4.2.1-1,...Groups: libraries'.
but when compiled in cmd/powershell it outputs:
"warning: GMP header version 6.3.0 differs from library version 6.2.1.
warning: MPFR header version 4.2.1 differs from library version 4.2.0-p9."
Where does it get the library of the old version (GMP 6.2.1,MPFR4.2.0-p9).
Can he watch it somewhere at MSVC?

You need to read What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?. gmp is the wrong package, you want mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gmp.

Thank you for the link! I will study it.
p.s. there were no problems with compilation before, it only appeared recently.

I have no idea what caused this issue but I solved it by reinstalling Windows.
For me the problem was even bigger because none of my MSys2 toolchains and none of winlibs.com toolchains worked correctly at all. I was getting the same linker error: 116 exit status.
I hope that someone will find a better solution than reinstalling Windows but if you are tired of looking for a solution, just keep in mind that this is also a working solution.

I have got the same problem, and add the PATH env pathto:git/mingw64/bin is ok to solve this problem.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I have a ucrt64 environment, not mingw64. my mingw64/bin folder is empty.
