CMake with msys64-ucrt64-g++ compiler does not build file with iostream functions calls
So I was following this tutorial on CMake in VSCode setup, and everything was going good, until I tried to build project. I chose preset for urct64/bin/g++.exe. The build process exits with error and prints:
[main] Building folder: C:/Users/maxka/VSC/cmake_learn/out/build/ucrt64 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: chcp
[proc] Executing command: C:\Cmake\bin\cmake.EXE --build C:/Users/maxka/VSC/cmake_learn/out/build/ucrt64 --parallel 10 --target cmake_learn --
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmake_learn.dir/main.cpp.obj
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable cmake_learn.exe
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 116 exit status
[build] mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmake_learn.dir\build.make:98: cmake_learn.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[3]: *** Deleting file 'cmake_learn.exe'
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:838: CMakeFiles/cmake_learn.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:845: CMakeFiles/cmake_learn.dir/rule] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:497: cmake_learn] Error 2
[proc] The command: C:\Cmake\bin\cmake.EXE --build C:/Users/maxka/VSC/cmake_learn/out/build/ucrt64 --parallel 10 --target cmake_learn -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:01.153
[build] Build finished with exit code 2

The .cpp file I am trying to run is:
#include <iostream>
// #include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    // printf("Hello world\n");
    cout << "Hello world\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}

When using stdio.h and printf instead of iostream and cout, it builds and works just fine.
Also, when changing the configuration preset from urct64/bin/g++ to mingw64/bin/g++ it builds with no problems, but .exe quits immideatly after start - it seems like it breaks on first iostream function call, because if both printf and cout are uncommented, printf works, but not cout. If these rearranged so cout is called first, both do not work.
CMakeLists is identical to one used in the tutorial:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(cmake_learn VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(cmake_learn main.cpp)

set_property(TARGET cmake_learn PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)


This doesn't look like a complete build log. There should be linker errors above [build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 116 exit status

@3CxEZiVlQ I added full build log to my question, as I understand there is no linker errors

If it builds, but doesn't run, that is often caused by incompatible runtime dlls found in the PATH.

linker is probably crashing due to incompatible dlls on the path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78556421/collect2-exe-error-ld-returned-116-exit-status

@AlanBirtles I am still not entirely sure about exact cause of my issue, but I reinstalled MSYS and made a new project in VSCode and now everything seems to work. Thank you!

Looks like there was indeed dll compatability problem due to my unorganized MSYS packages dowloads. I reinstalled MSYS and all packeges I needed and now it works.
